A PDE problem: heat eqaution with variables separation method
I have to solve a PDE problem called "Heat equation":
$
\begin{cases}
u_t = a^2u_{xx}+2xt,0<x<1, t>0 \\ u_x(0,t)=-1, u(1,t)=t \\ u(x,0) = 1-x-\cos(\frac{7\pi}{2}x)
\end{cases}
$
I started my solution with the following:
$
u(x,t) = v(x,t) + w(x,t) \\
w(x,t) = Ax+Bt \\
w_x = A \Rightarrow A=w_x(0,t)=-1 \\
w(1,t) = -1*1 + Bt = t \Rightarrow B=1+\frac{1}{t} \\
w(x,t) = -x+t+1 \\
v_t = a^2v_{xx}+2xt-1 \\
v_x(0,t) = 0 \\
v(1,t) = 0 \\
v(x,0) = -\cos(\frac{7\pi}{2}x)
$
Then I must apply separation of variables method to solve the resulting problem but despite all existing sources I can not proceed. Thank you in advance!

Before showing how to solve the problem, let's simplify it a little bit further. Let's rewrite $v$ as
$$
v(x,t)=V(x,t)-e^{-(7\pi a/2)^2t}\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{2}x\right). \tag{1}
$$
It's straightforward to verify that $V(x,t)$ satisfies the PDE
$$
V_t=a^2V_{xx}+2xt-1, \tag{2}
$$
subject to the boundary conditions
$$
V_x(0,t)=0, \qquad
V(1,t)=0, \tag{3}
$$
and the initial condition
$$
V(x,0)=0. \tag{4}
$$
Let's now write $V(x,t)$ as the series
$$
V(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(t)\varphi_n(x), \tag{5}
$$
where $\varphi_n(x)\,(n\in\mathbb{N})$ are the normalized eigenfuntions of $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ subject to the boundary conditions $\varphi_n'(0)=\varphi_n(1)=0$:
$$
\varphi_n(x)=\sqrt{2}\cos\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x\right)\qquad(n\in\mathbb{N}). \tag{6}
$$
Similarly, let's rewrite $2xt-1$ as
$$
2xt-1=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(t)\varphi_n(x), \tag{7}
$$
where
$$
f_n(t)=\int_0^1(2xt-1)\varphi_n(x)\,dx. \tag{8}
$$
Plugging $(5)$ and $(7)$ into the PDE $(2)$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dot{c}_n(t)\varphi_n(x)=
-a^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\pi^2c_n(t)\varphi_n(x)
+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(t)\varphi_n(x). \tag{9}
$$
It follows from the orthogonality of $\{\varphi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that $(9)$ is equivalent to the family of ODEs
$$
\dot{c}_n(t)=-\lambda_n c_n(t)+f_n(t)\qquad
\left[\lambda_n=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\pi^2a^2\right]. \tag{10}
$$
Solving $(10)$, and using the fact that the initial condition $V(x,0)=0$ implies $c_n(0)=0$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, we obtain
$$
c_n(t)=\int_0^{t}e^{-\lambda_n(t-t')}f_n(t')\,dt'. \tag{11}
$$
The problem is now formally solved: from the definitions of $v$ and $V$, we have
$$
u(x,t)=1-x+t-e^{-(7\pi a/2)^2t}\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{2}x\right)
+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(t)\varphi_n(x), \tag{12}
$$
where $\varphi_n(x)$ is given by $(6)$ and $c_n(t)$ is given by $(11)$ (with $f_n(t)$ and $\lambda_n$ defined in Eqs. $(8)$ and $(10)$, respectively). The functions $f_n(t)$ and $c_n(t)$ can be computed explicitly; I leave this task to you.

Great solution! Thank you so much!
